# How to use React with PowerBI custom visual

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

I'm trying to progress a Power BI Custom Visual react sample to the stage where it can access the dataViews of the parent visual in the React component.
The sample in question is https://github.com/ignatvilesov/powerbi-visuals-react-sample
Answers to this question may not require expertise in  Power BI custom visuals, knowledge of React may be sufficient.

In the Update method of the visual it create the calls `ReactDOM.render` like this: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), this.element);`

This works and creates a component that allows the react component to display elements in the visual.

When I attempt to pass the data options: VisualUpdateOptions like this: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App,{options} ), this.element);` , I am finding problems.

I don't understand how to get the options object using props, I've tried a variety of things, here is a sample of my attempts at an App.tsx

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    export class App extends React.Component<any,any> {

        constructor(props: VisualUpdateOptions) {
            super(props);                            
        }     
        public render() {

            var message = "";
            if (this.props == null){
                message = "no data"
            }
            else
            {
                message = "got data"
            }
            var message2 = "";
            if (this.props.dataViews == null)
            {
                message2 = "no dataview"
        }
            else
            {
                message2 = "got dataview"
            }
        ...
```

I get data ok, message2 always gives me no dataview.Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I have great ignorance in this area and seek enlightenment :-)

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.props)` to see if the `props` are coming and if that is the required props and check if `this.props.dataViews` also is coming correctly

Comment: It seems to me that `VisualUpdateOptions` is auto-wired and not something you can manually cook up (or get access to in app.tsx). If it was a pure react problem, the answer would be simple - pass props to `<app />` and make `app` pass them down to children. With power-vi, it seems a lot of heavy lifting and plumbing is done by the library itself and you get to hook into the process with various json files.

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/step-by-step-lab/creating-a-custom-visual/

Comment: Thanks @Mrchief , I have seen the step-by-step example. I've been using VisualUpdateOptions, it's just a normal JavaScript Object. It's that pass to the react App that is giving me the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to pass the props object to create element inside the visual.ts (where you create an instance of the react app). Something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {"yourProp": "props"}), this.element);
```

Console log the props as you are doing now, you should see them.

Comment: Aha! I just changed to debugging in Chrome, now I can see inside objects from Console.log. Would your example would create a property called "yourProp" (props.yourProp) with a string value "props"? I'm going to run it as a test later, before doing the larger object.

Comment: Yeah that's what you would see there. Let me know, I am very curious.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly and when I use ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {"options": options}) ,this.element); it passes the object. Dziękuję @Lukasz

Comment: Oops! almost forgot the bounty :-)